# zend studio 7 creating .sharedentries and .listing

Tags: php, editor, zend-studio

i created project in zend studio and there are files called .sharedentries and .listing gets created on all folders and sub folders of the project, its annoying, cause i would have to delete all these files and then upload. does anyone know what can i do to turn this off, so it dont create it anymore?

Comment: This project is under SVN or Git repos?